# Flutter / Supabase - how to find table record count?

Tags: flutter, supabase

I'm using Supabase for my Flutter app.

I can't find a way of finding the total record count in a Supabase table.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you should get the count as follows:

```
void main() async {
    final res = await supabase
    .from(tableName)
    .select('count(*)') 
    .execute();
 final totalRecords = res.data?[0]['count'] as int? ?? 0;
 if (res.error != null) {
 print('Error: ${res.error!.message}');
 } else {
 final totalRecords = res.data?.length ?? 0;
  print('Total Records: $totalRecords');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
final aRes = await client.from(table).select('*',FetchOptions(count: CountOption.exact) );

return aRes.count;
```

Answer (score 0):

FetchOptions have since been deprecated and you should get count as follows:

```
await supabase
    .from(table)
    .count()
    .eq('id',1);
```